# Year Out Of Range In Python?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have an Open Source application installed on my system, designed in python, now I am trying to insert a date older then 1900, it results in an error `**Year Out Of Range**` Now I am thinking to resolve it so that it will allow me to store any date from 1000 - 9999 years. Is this error due to python or because of my application, any suggestions and solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Be careful with years before 1600. I'd outright refuse them.

Comment: Fails for Nov 5th 1605 on Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a reported [python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1777412). A patch is available at that address.

Comment: Well I am using Python 2.6 and This is for 3.2, Do u have a link for 2.6 patch

Comment: [2.6 patch](https://github.com/minitage-dependencies/python-2.6/raw/master/patches/strftime-pre-1900.patch)

Comment: I am unable to find this file on my PC.."Lib/test/test_datetime.py" I am using python 2.6.5. when i try to locate datetime.py i found the following results

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mx/DateTime/mxDateTime/testpydatetime.py..........

/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/zope/interface/common/idatetime.py......

/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/zope/interface/common/tests/test_idatetime.py........

/usr/share/pyshared/mx/DateTime/mxDateTime/testpydatetime.py.....

/usr/share/pyshared/zope/interface/common/tests/test_idatetime.py.....

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a patch that could work on Python 2.6.5. Have you thought of using isoformat, that works on datetime instances without date limitation ?
    >>> import datetime
    >>> x=datetime.datetime(1850, 2, 1, 3, 28, 15)
    >>> x.isoformat()

Comment: @ Mademoiselle Geek Thanks a lot for your help but that will be very complex for me Coz I have a large application and it will be very much difficult to use this every where. Can i upgrade my python 2.6.5 to 2.6.6 so that i can use the above patch

Comment: If it is possible for you to upgrade to 2.6.6, you could indeed use the above patch.